Install of latest CiviCRM on latest Joomla - Debian 12
I'm receiving the following when trying to install the latest version on my system:
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError:
Compile Error: Declaration of Psr\Log\NullLogger::log($level, $message, array $context = []) must be compatible with Psr\Log\AbstractLogger::log($level, Stringable|string $message, array $context = []): void

  at /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/psr/log/Psr/Log/NullLogger.php:26   

I'm following the instructions at https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/joomla/
Advice is welcomed.
Thank you,
Larry

This is a known incompatibility between Joomla 5 and CiviCRM. The issue is being tracked here: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/joomla/-/issues/54

Please have a look on how to fix this HERE.
Replace line 26 in the file com_civicrm/admin/civicrm/vendor/psr/log/Psr/Log/NullLogger.php, change it from public function log($level, $message, array $context = array()) to public function log($level, $message, array $context = []): void.
